# How to get the actual wrong value from a broken query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a very long query for insert, it gives me a "ORA-01722: invalid number" error, which is pretty simple thing usually. But this time i need to know what **IN FACT** value is wrong.

How do I do that?
I used construction

```
BEGIN
--longest spaghetti ever
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: '||sqlerrm);
END;
```

But it only gives me that damn error code and nothing more.

Comment: It **may** help: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0600__System-Tables-Data-Dictionary/Getdetailederrormessagefromusererrors.htm

Comment: You are basically going to be debugging the SQL statement so I suggest you extract it from the PL/SQL block, get the SELECT statement associated with the insert - which I assume is why it is such long query - and start breaking it down to establish which number is the one in error. It can be tedious but you will certainly understand that query by the time you're finished.

Comment: also just a good discussion of logging issues with exception handling here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-mar/o22plsql-1518275.html

Comment: Usually an invalid number error occurs when you are trying to convert/insert a varchar2 into a number column, oracle uses the implicit conversion in statements, so you can start with this info if you follow the suggestion by @BriteSponge which is a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you work on 10g or above, you can use `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK`. It will return the full error message.  With this, you can get the line number that you get error and you can zoom right in on the problem.

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    my_putline (
       DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
END;
```

Comment: Or you could just not catch the exception at all; but this still won't tell you which value caused the ORA-01722?

Comment: with this you can log the error, especially if you want to solve an issue in production code it is better to catch the exception

Comment: There's an app for that: https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2

Comment: thank you for the contribution @Stilgar  This app is really useful

Comment: Of course that only works on the INSERT portion; I guess we haven't determined if the error is on the insert or on the SELECT

Comment: It occures both in INSERT opeation, and in SELECT from which I do the INSERT